# How do i apply ownership and permissions recursively onto a directory using another directory as reference in linux

Tags: linux, bash

Folder A has correct ownership and permissions on all its files/subfolders.
Folder B exact same content but with ownership and permissions messed up. Need to apply chmod/chown using Folder B as reference on everything under FOlder A.

Answer (score 1):

Using --reference option the chmod command is capable to clone permissions from one file/directory to another

```
 $ chmod --reference=FolderB FolderA
```